# Why the performance of concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor is very low?

Tags: python-3.x, threadpool, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures, process-pool

I'm trying to leverage `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` in `Python3` to process a large matrix in parallel. The general structure of the code is:

```
class X(object):

self.matrix

def f(self, i, row_i):
    <cpu-bound process>

def fetch_multiple(self, ids):
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(self.f, i, self.matrix.getrow(i)) for i in ids]
        return [f.result() for f in as_completed(futures)]
```

`self.matrix` is a large [scipy csr_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html). `f` is my concurrrent function that takes a row of `self.matrix` and apply a **CPU-bound** process on it. Finally, `fetch_multiple` is a function that run multiple instance of `f` in parallel and returns the results.

The problem is that after running the script, all cpu cores are less than 50% busy (See the following screenshot):

[image]

Why all cores are not busy?

I think the problem is the large object of `self.matrix` and passing row vectors between processes. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. 
The overhead should not be that big - but it is likely the cause of your CPUs appearing iddle (although, they should be busy passing the data around anyway).

But try the recipe here to pass a "pointer" of the object to the subprocess using shared memory.

http://briansimulator.org/sharing-numpy-arrays-between-processes/

Quoting from there:

```
from multiprocessing import sharedctypes
size = S.size
shape = S.shape
S.shape = size
S_ctypes = sharedctypes.RawArray('d', S)
S = numpy.frombuffer(S_ctypes, dtype=numpy.float64, count=size)
S.shape = shape
```

> Now we can send S_ctypes and shape to a child process in
>   multiprocessing, and convert it back to a numpy array in the child
>   process as follows:

```
from numpy import ctypeslib
S = ctypeslib.as_array(S_ctypes)
S.shape = shape
```

It should be tricky to take care of reference counting, but I suppose `numpy.ctypeslib` takes care of that - so, just coordinate the passing of the actual row number to sub-processes in a way they don't work on the same data